# action script 3 read values from XML file

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I have a problem while reading from XML file in action script 3.

This is my XML-file:

```
<config>

    <production>
        <app_id>123</app_id>
        <server_path>http://someLinktoAccess</server_path>
        <assets_server>http://someLinktoAccess</assets_server>
        <payment_url_callback>http://someLinktoAccess</payment_url_callback>
    </production>

    <stage>
        <app_id>123</app_id>
        <server_path>http://someLinktoAccess</server_path>
        <assets_server>http://someLinktoAccess</assets_server>
        <payment_url_callback>http://someLinktoAccess</payment_url_callback>
    </stage>

    <dev>
        <app_id>123</app_id>
        <server_path>http://someLinktoAccess</server_path>
        <assets_server>http://someLinktoAccess</assets_server>
        <payment_url_callback>http://someLinktoAccess</payment_url_callback>
    </dev>

    </config>
```

**I want to access to each key-value pair in this file. So I want to get from here 4 string variables: app_id, server_path, assets_server, payment_url_callback. How can I get them??**

Now I'm using such a code:

```
private function loadXmlConfig():void
        {
            //load the loading config xml
            var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            var load_config_path:String = "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/28744968/android_vs.xml";
            xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlConfigLoadingSuccessed);
            xmlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,  xmlConfigLoadingFailed);
            xmlLoader.load( new URLRequest( load_config_path ) );
        }

        private function xmlConfigLoadingSuccessed(event:Event):void
        {
            var load_config:XML = new XML( event.target.data );
            trace(load_config.config.dev.app_id.value);
            //startup facade
            GameFacade.getInstance().startup( StartupCommand, this );
        }
```

The file is loaded with all values, but I can't access any of them.

What mean this:

```
var library:XML
 library.@url
```

Thank you!

Comment: try using `XMLList` http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XMLList.html

Comment: @yozhik you have `trace(load_config.config.dev.app_id.value);`, try `trace(load_config.dev.app_id.value);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using XML class you do not reference the root node in your case "config"

```
// your code
trace(load_config.config.dev.app_id.value);

// correct code
// the toString method should be called automatically
trace(load_config.production.app_id);
```

And to answer your other question.

```
var library:XML
 library.@url
```

the @ symbol is used to access attributes.

```
<library id=123 >
```

Why are you putting your config file as an xml anyway?
This Type of thing I create a config file/class/Singleton for.

Comment: I'm using xml-file because my servers can move from one to another freequently, and to avoid recompile my app - I'm using xml file with all configs there and I can modify them easily.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution for this, maby it helps anyone later:

```
    private function loadXmlConfig():void
    {
        //load the loading config xml
        var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        var load_config_path:String = "http://linkToConfigFile";
        xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlConfigLoadingSuccessed);
        xmlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,  xmlConfigLoadingFailed);
        xmlLoader.load( new URLRequest( load_config_path ) );
    }

    private function xmlConfigLoadingSuccessed(event:Event):void
    {
        var load_config:XML = new XML( event.target.data );
        var listOfProperties:XMLList = load_config.elements("dev");
        var listOfElements:XMLList = listOfProperties[0].elements();
        this.f_vars = new Object();

        for each (var xmlObj:XML in listOfElements)
        {
            this.f_vars[xmlObj.name()] = xmlObj.valueOf();
            trace(this.f_vars[xmlObj.name()]);
        }

        //startup facade

    }
```