# how to extract values from an xml tree using actionscript

Tags: actionscript

I have an xml tree as below

```
<Response>
<Terminal>
<Name>m1</Name>
<Value><Array1><DBL><Val>-0.143077</Val></DBL></Array1></Value>
</Terminal>
<Terminal>
<Name>m3</Name>
<Value><Array3><DBL><Val>-0.876611</Val></DBL></Array3></Value>
</Terminal>
<Terminal>
<Name>m2</Name>
<Value><Array2><DBL><Val>-0.459437</Val></DBL></Array2></Value>
</Terminal>
</Response>
```

I have to extract m1,m2,m3 values using action script

Can anyone help me in writing this code .

Is the below code is enough for this

```
for (var i=0; i<xml.Terminal.length(); i++) {

     if (xml.Terminal.Name.text()=="m1") {

                       voltage=xml.Terminal.Value.Array1.DBL.Val.text()
                              }
     else if (xml.Terminal[i].Name.text()=="m2") {

                      current=xml.Terminal.Value.Array2.DBL.Val.text();

                              }
     else if (xml.Terminal[i].Name.text()=="m3") {

                       temperature=xml.Terminal.Value.Array3.DBL.Val.text();

                            }
        }

        Menu_Content1.volt_val.text = voltage;
    Menu_Content1.curr_val.text = current;
    Menu_Content1.temp_val.text = temperature;
)
```

volt_val.text etc is for text display added in flash.

Answer (score 2):

To parse a common formated tags in XML you have to first place them into a parent tage in your case create XML like this

```
<Response>
<**PARENT_TAG**>
<Terminal>
<Name>m1</Name>
<Value><Array1><DBL><Val>-0.143077</Val></DBL></Array1></Value>
</Terminal>
<Terminal>
<Name>m3</Name>
<Value><Array3><DBL><Val>-0.876611</Val></DBL></Array3></Value>
</Terminal>
<Terminal>
<Name>m2</Name>
<Value><Array2><DBL><Val>-0.459437</Val></DBL></Array2></Value>
</Terminal>
</**PARENT_TAG**>
</Response>
```

After that parsing of an XML in actionscript is very easy you just have to create an object of a XML  and than use DOM format to get value of a particular tag As an example

```
var result:XML = new XML(event.target.data);

for(var i:int=0; i<result.PARENT_TAG.length; i++)
{
   trace(result.PARENT_TAG.Terminal[i].Name);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes,your idea is lead to right move.but you should first load xml file in object.
You can use XML like [here](http://www.blog.mpcreation.pl/actionscript-30-basics-part-3-loading-xml-data/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402440/action-script-3-read-values-from-xml-file) in your project.